# change start url in nodejs app from / to /foo

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The point is that I want is to go to the site and its default(index) url will be something like `localhost:XXXX/foo`, unlike the default pf `localhost:XXXX/`

How can I realize that?

Comment: Are you using vanilla node or express?

Comment: The routes are easily changed.  The links emitted by an app tend to be more tedious to find and correct.

Comment: @somekittens-ux2666 express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all hits to `/` to be redirected to `/foo` in express:

```
app.all('/', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/foo');
});
```